# Connection refused Chromecast Sender / receiver application

Tags: javascript, jquery, casting, chromecast

i'm new to the cast sdk.

I've started to build a application for the Google Chromecast, and so far nothing good has come up.
Things i've done:

- Got a Cast SDK developer console account
- Registered my Chromecast
- Published my application

My application is really simple, i just cloned this one: https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world

I just changed the applicationid used in the project to my Application id i got on the cast developer console. For namespace i just used my own namespace (hwproject)

I hope someone can help me a bit further, i'm stuck for 18 hours now.

Comment: Where do you see connection refused? Did you check the checkbox to send your serial number during your chromecast setup? Explaining exactly where things are not working will enable us to give you more targeted suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment:

When i go on the receiver page, i get the following: http://justpaste.it/hnif

Comment: I am not familiar with that project. Have you tried any of the official sample projects at https://github.com/googlecast?